# Trying to compare two strings

Tags: php, string, strcmp

I'm trying to compare two strings. One of them is a session (`id_usr`), the other is sent via a `HTTP GET REQUEST`.

First I check if the user is logged in and then i want to check if the user who  is logged in has the same user id as the one sent via the GET request.

```
$id_user = $_GET['id_user'];
$id_user_session = isset($_SESSION['id_usr']);

if(isset($_SESSION) && strcmp($id_user, $id_user_session) == 0) {
    echo 'x';
}
```

Both values look good when i get them, but the compare function `strcmp` doesn't work.

What am i missing?

Comment: Have you printed in such a way that you can see whitespace?

Comment: what you get with this `if($id_user == $id_user_session){
    echo 'Equal';
}else{ echo 'Not Equal'; }`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$id_user_session = isset($_SESSION['id_usr']);
```

to

```
$id_user_session = $_SESSION['id_usr'];
```

also make sure that you have started your session with `session_start();`before trying to access `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @AleixGalletSegarra The function `isset()` returns `true` or `false`. Meaning, that `$id_user_session` is probably `true`. Just wanted to add this, just in case you are wondering why it's not working.

Comment: ok, so isset just tell you if a user has or not a session, i understand. Thanks!